# How to stop a tetris piece in java?

Tags: java, swing, tetris

I'm writing a code for Tetris game and I have a problem with pieces moves. I made them move right, left and down, I made them rotate but when the pieces reach its bottom line I couldn't make them stop and draw a new piece to the top. Here are my classes:

Shape classes for each shape which extends an abstract Shape class and I have made turning part in here too.

```
  public class TShape extends Shape{

   public TShape(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    super(x, y, w, h);

}

public void draw(Graphics g){

    if (TetrisFrame.turn ==0){
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);


        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x+w, y, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x+w, y, w, h);


        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x+2*w, y, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x+2*w, y, w, h);


        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x+w, y+h, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x+w, y+h, w, h);

    }

 if(TetrisFrame.turn ==1){
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x-w, y, w, h);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x-w, y, w, h);


    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x-w, y+h, w, h);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x-w, y+h, w, h);


    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x-2*w, y+h, w, h);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x-2*w, y+h, w, h);


    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x-w, y+2*h, w, h);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x-w, y+2*h, w, h);

}


 if (TetrisFrame.turn ==2){

     g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x-2*w, y-h, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x-2*w, y-h, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x-3*w, y, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x-3*w, y, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x-2*w, y, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x-2*w, y, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x-w, y, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x-w, y, w, h);

 }

 if (TetrisFrame.turn ==3){

     g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x-w, y-3*h, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x-w, y-3*h, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x-w, y-2*h, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x-w, y-2*h, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x-w, y-h, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x-w, y-h, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(x, y-2*h, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x, y-2*h, w, h);

     }

   }
 }
```

Draw panel to draw the shapes:

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel{
int x = 150;
int y =0;
int h=30;
int w=30;

Shape s;

public DrawPanel(){

    s = new TShape(x,y,w,h);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

     super.paintComponent(g);
    s.draw(g);

    }
```

My Tetris frame and handlers:

```
public class TetrisFrame extends JFrame{

 DrawPanel dp;

 static int turn;

public TetrisFrame(){

    dp= new DrawPanel();
    dp.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 3));

    MyHandler mhd = new MyHandler();

    this.addKeyListener(mhd);

    getContentPane().add(dp);


}

class MyHandler implements KeyListener{

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        //left:37,  right:39,  up:38  down:40

        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if(code == 37){

            dp.s.x -=30;

        }
       if(code == 38){

           turn++;

           if (turn ==4)
               turn =0;
        }

        if(code == 39){

           dp.s.x +=30;

         }

       if(code == 40){

          dp.s.y +=30;
           if(dp.s.y == 17*30){

              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "fvgbhn");

          }
     }




    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         dp.repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



  }
}
```

what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Where is the logic that makes your bloc go down ? You need some kind of engine class that makes your tetrominos go down, which calls another class which checks for collisons, and once it collides with another block, stops and generates another one. You'll have some kind of list of tetrominos and the drawing class will use it to draw every tetromino. I wouldn't have used this architecture, it's gonna be difficult when blocks starts disappearing in the middle of the screen. But as long as you have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: I tried the posted code out, but there are quite a few errors. Are you sure you have posted the complete code? If you wish to maintain your code's privacy, that's fine, and you can try the following out.**

I see. You haven't set conditions for whether the piece has reached the bottom.

First of all, you shouldn't be setting a variable for the height and width of the blocks. You should give it a pre-defined value, like `10` (In Pixels).

Let's say you want to set the border as a rectangle `0, 0, 300, 500`, this will be your code:

```
if (TetrisFrame.turn ==0){

if(y+h >= 500)
{
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x, (500 - h), w, h);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x, (500 - h), w, h);

    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x+w, (500 - h), w, h);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x+w, (500 - h), w, h);


    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x+2*w, (500 - h), w, h);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x+2*w, (500 - h), w, h);


    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x+w, 500, w, h);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x+w, 500, w, h);
}
else
{
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);


    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x+w, y, w, h);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x+w, y, w, h);


    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x+2*w, y, w, h);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x+2*w, y, w, h);


    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(x+w, y+h, w, h);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(x+w, y+h, w, h);
}
}
```

Comment: I added my Tshape class too, it reaches to the bottom but I couldn't make it draw a new shape to the top of the frame